# ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key recaptcha google

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

hi guys i'm using google recaptcha in my site. At first she was working normally but after some days i get this error E`RROR for site owner: Invalid site key` and i receive this alert `We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information.` in my account google

> i use this code to validate recaptcha response

```
    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
    ]);
```

Comment: as it says, you may need to regenerate api key or verify the site again

Answer (score 1):

mine was giving a similar error and I finally solved the problem on the Google captcha admin console by unchecking the box next to “Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions”